# Not able to connect to AS in Docker container

Tags: jboss, docker, application-server

I have created a docker image from a dockerfile, started it on a local VM (boot2docker), and verified from application server logs that it is running and deployed ok. However, I am not able to connect to the AS from my Windows client.

The end of my dockerfile:

```
RUN echo "JAVA_OPTS=\"\$JAVA_OPTS -Djboss.bind.address=0.0.0.0 -Djboss.bind.address.management=0.0.0.0\"" >> $JBOSS_HOME/bin/standalone.conf

# Expose ports
EXPOSE 9990 9999 8080 80 8787

# Start server
ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/jboss-eap-6.3/bin/standalone.sh"]
```

I have also tried adding "-p 8080:8080" when running the container. Browser does not open the welcome page, and telnetting "192.168.99.100 8080" (IP of the VM) does not go through. Any ideas to why I cannot connect from my windows client to  VM running the AS in container? I am able to ssh to the VM, so connection otherwise is not an issue.

Comment: Check if any bind to `localhost` setting in your java application, which you need adjust to `0.0.0.0`, this can expose the port 8080 to outside, otherwise, it limits the access in container.

Comment: some virus shields are so aggrssively protecting the localhost,maybe you have some local firewall issues...